# Vite dev server not shutting down in ASP.NET react app

Tags: reactjs, asp.net, vite

I've a react app setup with Vite and ASP.NET, with an npm start command like:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "vite" 
}
```

In the ASP.NET `startup.cs` I have:

```
spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    spa.Options.DevServerPort = 5173;
    spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
}
```

Which all successfully starts up the asp.net app, starts the vite dev server and I am able to navigate to my react app.

However, when I stop the ASP.NET app, the Vite server does not stop, which means it is holding on to port 5173. The only way I can now restart the app is to use the kill command in powershell to kill the running Vite server.

Is there a way I can have Vite automatically shutdown when I stop the ASP.NET app?

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution:
You can add a custom middleware in your ASP.NET app's `Startup.cs` to stop the Vite dev server when the ASP.NET app is shutting down. This middleware would be responsible for sending a request to the Vite dev server's shutdown endpoint. Here's an example of how you can achieve this:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    // Your existing configuration

    // Add this middleware to gracefully stop the Vite dev server
    app.ApplicationStopping.Register(() =>
    {
        // Determine the URL of your Vite dev server's shutdown endpoint
        string viteShutdownUrl = "http://localhost:5173/__vite_ping";

        // Send a request to the Vite dev server's shutdown endpoint
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            // Make a request to the Vite server's shutdown endpoint
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(viteShutdownUrl).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            // Optionally, you can check the response status and handle errors
            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                // Handle the error if needed
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Make sure to replace `"http://localhost:5173/__vite_ping"` with the actual URL of your Vite dev server's shutdown endpoint. This endpoint is provided by Vite to gracefully shut down the dev server.

Adding this middleware will ensure that when your ASP.NET app is shutting down, it sends a request to the Vite dev server to shut down as well, releasing the port it's using.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm not able to find a shutdown endpoint on Vite's website, do you know if it exists?